# Jmeter - CSV Data Config file name - Modify at RunTime

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

How can I change the filename of the CSV DataConfig at run time in the jmx file.

We have a logic in a java class which would create a dynamic file name and this

needs to be configured as the filename in the CSV DataConfig.

I am using Jmeter 4.0

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You could use a variable / property name in the CSV data set config

here filename could be the name of the file or complete path of the file itself could be used as a variable.

Remember that CSV Data set config element gets initialized first - so filename should be a User defined variable / could be a property passed to JMeter. I would prefer a property.

[image]

**Do note that You can not keep on changing the CSV data set config element filename in a test once it started. That means one CSV Data set config element can be used for 1 CSV file only. We can not modify!!**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as CSV Data Set Config is a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) therefore it's executed before **anything else**. If you need to read the data from different files as the test goes by consider using [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) instead, the most suitable ones would be:

- [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) - returns the next string from the given file each time it's called
- [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) - reads a value from CSV file. The function not only supports using dynamic file names, moreover, you can provide even multiple input files as well.